# Game Center not showing in Fullscreen (MacOS / xcode)

Tags: xcode, sdl, fullscreen, game-center, osx-mountain-lion

I'm developing a MacOS application.
Since Mountain Lion (10.8) it is possible to add Game Center to OS X applications.
I've added one, tested it, and it works fine, but only in windowed mode. If I go fullscreen with my app, I can no longer see Game Center windows (authentication window nor match finding).
What can be the problem? I'm using SDL and OpenGL. I know that SDL uses Cocoa to set up the application's window.
Game Center for OS X uses GKDialogController to show and dismiss windows, but there isn't much to tweak there. One thing that came to my mind was setting parent window as follows:

```
self.dialogController.parentWindow = [NSApp mainWindow];
```

But nothing changed. There is a brief pause when i access the Game Center, so it seems everything is working ok in fullscreen, just the window is not shown. How to bring that window in fullscreen to be visible / frontal ? Is there something to be changed in OpenGL or in SDL? Or is this impossible and I'd need to switch to native window creating?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Just as a follow-up I ended up rolling my own native Cocoa backend in order to have Game Center function optimally. SDL as it stands currently isn't a good option when Game Center is in the mix.